# Gatsby + Shopify query page from shopisify is it possible?

Tags: graphql, shopify, gatsby

I try to build a site from Shopify API with Gatsby.
I manage to query information from product, but I don't find a way to query the page from Shopify. I don't find in `graphQl` something like `allShopifyPages` that can give the information, description, title or anything else about the page who has been created in Shopify. So my question is possible and if yes how ?
Below the examples of page content I want to query in `graphql`
I've opened a discussion on Gatsby but nobody answered from few months.
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/33394

[image]

Comment: There is a already a working Gatsby Shopify site out there. Why not clone it, and then you have a solid foundation to work from. Note, there are other JS front-ends too. All will reveal tips and tricks.

Comment: I think there is miss understanding. I've already a

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know pages, then you have to query the right endpoints. If you examine the RestAPI, you'll find:

```
https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/page#top
```

That gives you exactly what you are looking for. I am not sure what the analog is for GQL, there might not be one at this time, but you are free to search.

Comment: Thanks for the link I add this information to the https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/33394 maybe there is good dev can work on it. Because that's can be helpful for the beginner like me to can grab content page from Gatsby to use it in Gatsby.